# SAP BO Webi 4.1 Create Variable that returns the value of another variable

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I have a narrow dataset: `AgentID, Name, Date, Code, StartTime, EndTime`.  I created a Detail variable titled "`TimeDiff`" that returns the difference between `StartTime` and `EndTime` as an integer representing the minutes between the two timestamps.

For each date, each agent has at least 6 rows, where the `Code`, `StartTime` and `EndTime` reveal Agent scheduled activity.

Example:

| AgentID | Name | Date | Code | StartTime | EndTime | TimeDiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Agent123 | Bob Jones | 01/01/2016 | ShiftXYZ | 07:00:00 | 15:00:00 | 480 |
| Agent123 | Bob Jones | 01/01/2016 | BREAK1 | 09:00:00 | 09:15:00 | 15 |
| Agent123 | Bob Jones | 01/01/2016 | LUNCH | 12:00:00 | 12:30:00 | 30 |
| Agent123 | Bob Jones | 01/01/2016 | BREAK1 | 14:00:00 | 14:15:00 | 15 |

Some times are additive, like `ShiftXYZ`. Some are subtractive, like `BREAK1`, `BREAK2`, etc. (there are 48 unique codes in all).  In another report, I would like to sum the `TimeDiff` for each group of codes.  I've tried a few different approaches, such as creating a measure with the formula:

```
=Sum([Variables].[TimeDiff])Where([Code] Not In("ShiftXYZ"; "ShiftABC"))    
=If [Code] InList("BREAK1";"BREAK2") Then Sum([Variables].[TimeDiff]
```

and various permutations of each approach.  I get lots of different error messages but not the output I want.

Can anyone suggest either the outright answer or suggest a better approach?  I suspect I'm missing some element. I would appreciate any suggestions.

--mfc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it.  Here's one:

```
=Sum(If [Code] InList ("BREAK1";"BREAK2") Then [TimeDiff] Else 0)
```